# Python 2d list - after changing element, no change in print ouput

Tags: python

I created a 2d list in python and want to change an element. It works fine, but for some reason with two different printing-ways, i get two different results. By printing the whole array out, i get as desired, an array of zeros. By explicitly printing out the element, which was changed, i get a different result:

```
m = 4
n = 3

a4 = [[0]*m for i in range(n)]

for row in a4:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()

print("####")
a4[0][0] = 1
print(a4[0][0])

for row in a4:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()
```

Both loops are printing a 3x4-array with zeros, although a4[0][0] was changed to 1 in an intermediate step. Why is that?

Comment: What is `i`? And what exactly are you asking?

Comment: for element in a4[i] --> for element in row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too sure you are printing correctly, since when you are doing `a4[i]`, `i` should be undefined. Give a go to:

```
m = 4
n = 3

a4 = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]

for zeile in a4:
    for element in zeile:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()

print("####")
a4[0][0] = 1
print(a4[0][0])
print("####")

for zeile in a4:
    for element in zeile:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
####
1
####
1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
```

First element is changed to 1 as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Where is "i" declared and modified?
I don't know how you want to do it, but below code worked for me fine.

```
m = 4
n = 3

a4 = [[0]*m for i in range(n)]

for row in a4:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()

print("####")
a4[0][0] = 1
print(a4[0][0])

for row in a4:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be defining i somewhere before your posted block of code. The loops are displaying the row at the index of i. Set i to 0 right before your code block and it should display what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your change is actually fine. The issue is you are indexing by i which is set to n-1 due to this line:

```
a4 = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]
```

if you print as such, you'll see the change was actually OK:

```
for row in a4:
    print row

print("####")
a4[0][0] = 1
print(a4[0][0])

for row in a4:
    print row
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
####
1
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
```